# iOS app crashes whenever I visit this question

Tags: bug, ios-app

Got a couple inbox notifications on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98376/solidworks-epdm-add-in/101359#101359) and every time i click one, the question starts to load and as soon as the app tries to scroll down to the answer, it crashes and I'm taken to the home screen.

When I double-tap home button and activate the SE app again, it takes me back to wherever I was before I tried to go to the question linked above.

This happens no matter how I try to access the question - e.g. From inbox, from my profile, from navigating to it from the CR site, or from the link in this post.

I can access the question just fine in safari, but it crashes this app every time.

I'm running on an iPhone 6 plus:
  - model: MGAU2LL/A
  - version: 8.3 (12F70)
  - firmware: 2.23.03
  - SE app version: 1.3.2 (App Store version)

Comment: I can reproduce this on my iPhone. I suspect it is due to too much code having been posted in the question.

Comment: No-repro in 1.3.2.218 on iOS 8.1. Also, by what you've described, the app does quit. The app won't be removed from the 'multitasking' because it's not a multitasking list, but a list of recent apps. The app on iOS restores the last state of the app when you relaunch it, but it really is crashing. If your device is jailbroken, you can obtain a symbolicated crash log with CrashReporter, or alternatively you can use Diagnostics & Usage in Settings, or Xcode in OS X to obtain a normal crash log.

Comment: @PolyGeo - "too much code" is kind of a misnomer. Given the purpose of the CR site, I'd say the app just hasn't been developed to support it properly.  @

Comment: @grgarside - my iPhone is not jail broken, but I will update my post to indicate this is a crash and I will add my iPhone details.

Comment: Can you add the app version? Are you using a beta or the App Store version?

Comment: In case it helps I am seeing this on an iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1.2.

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this.  I'm not seeing crash reports from August 19, suggesting this is a memory issue *but* I've profiled loading the question and it seems fine.

Comment: The link in this question causes a crash on my ipad 4 64Gb (md512b/a).  Likewise I get a crash from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/53921485?noredirect=1).

Comment: @BrianNickel - that link crashed my app as well, still the same iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: "Related" shows ten things making the app crash!  But for what it's worth, it has never crashed on my iPad of iPhone.   (What's the emoticon for "fingers crossed"?)